# Name of a Star Wars (EU) "Collection"

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, books, star-wars-legends

About maybe 15 years ago, here in Germany (probably existed in other countries, too, but I don't know for sure), there was a Star Wars collection. I don't know how to name it otherwise. It was something where you subscribed to a magazine and got weekly issues with some pages, which you could collect in given folders.

I think it was officially licensed stuff. It contained a lot of information about the stories happened in the movies, but also about planets, species, technology and also a lot of information which is now considered EU, like things that happened long after ROTJ. It also had a lot of very detailed blueprints of ships, crafts and weapons.

I don't have those old folders anymore, and they were not complete back then (still I had 3 or 4 folders with estimated 300 pages). I want to see if I can find this collection somewhere online or in physical form, but I don't know what to look for other than "Star Wars Collection". Maybe someone knows what I mean and can give me additional information about it.

I know that I can probably find all information I ever wanted to know about Star Wars in some Wikis, but I liked that collection.

Comment: You can find all the information you ever want to know about Star Wars by searching here and if it’s not on here yet by asking here ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be the [The Official Star Wars Fact File](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File).

This was published by De Agostini as a weekly magazine between 2002 and 2005.  It ran for 140 editions and was organized into six major categories:

- Battles & Events
- Characters
- Planets & Locations
- Droids
- Weapons & Technology
- Vehicles

It was published in Germany and in most of Europe

Comment: Yep, the Fact File, that was it. Thank you =)

Comment: Glad to help :), I saw the adverts for this collection here in the UK at the time, but wasn't in the position to collect them.  I guess it stuck in my memory though - Star Wars geek that I can be ;)